# UITableView - Interaction with the table view disappearing everything

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UITableView`, and added it as a `subview` of a `UIView`.
Whenever I select a cell that had everything disappears in `UITableView`.

Already had this problem at other times, however it stopped happening without changes on code.

Currently I use Swift, however already happened in Objective-C.

Code:

TableView delegates:

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView
numberOfRowsInSection
cellForRowAtIndexPath
heightForRowAtIndexPath
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

Also registered the identifier of the `cell`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        listObjectsToList = ["String 1","String 2","String 3"]

        self.view.frame.size = CGSizeMake(300, 110)
        self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listObjectsToList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = listObjectsToList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let objectSelected: AnyObject = listObjectsToList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        object.type = objectSelected as String
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

However the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called...

Code adding tableview:

```
        var listTypeTableViewController = ListTypeTableViewController()
        listTypeTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 130)
        self.view.addSubview(listTypeTableViewController.view)
```

I have tried:

```
        var listTypeTableViewController = ListTypeTableViewController()
        listTypeTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 130)
        self.view.addSubview(listTypeTableViewController.tableView)
```

But without success

Comment: Need more info to help you. How are you implementing your data source methods?

Comment: OK I'm more used to Objective-C but 1) is the table view strongly retained by `self`? because the table view could be being released prior to when you want it to and 2) If your didSelectRowAtIndexPath is successfully called then obviously your entire view will disappear which may explain what's happening.

Comment: @RASS `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not called :/

Comment: OK are you retaining your table view when you add it to its subview?

Comment: @RASS Yes. It appears correctly with the data, however when I select any option the content disappear. Leaving only the tableview and empty cells

Comment: I don't know then. Maybe your datasource array is being deleted or released somewhere but that's all I can think of.

Comment: @RASS Thanks, I will continue the work here, and if I find I bring the solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem was and I was just trying to extract the `UITableView` to show it. When I need to add a `UITableViewController` as a child of my `UIViewController`:

```
var listTypeTableViewController = ListTypeTableViewController(nibName: "TableViewTypeScheduling", bundle: nil)        
listTypeTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 130)        
addChildViewController(listTypeTableViewController)
view.addSubview(listTypeTableViewController.view)
```

Comment: for me, ```addChildViewController(listTypeTableViewController)``` that solves the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method:

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

You remove a view and all of its superviews, including the table view.

Comment: However the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called...And nothing is removed from the screen, just the contents of the table view disappears

Comment: Are you sure? Put a breakpoint in this method and check it. And if it's not called, then how can anything happen (including the table view disappearing) when a cell is selected?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Was the first thing I checked

Comment: And where do you initialize `listObjectsToList`? It's not initialized in the code you posted

Comment: And where do you add `tableView` as a subview to `self.view`? Where do you initialize the table view and set delegate and data source? I can't see this in code either

Comment: As @Gian states, you initialize `ListTypeTableViewController` programmatically. So, unless you load _nib_ file somewhere in your code,  the table view would never been initialized. So, how did you initialize the table view? And has anything ever show up in the first place? Or they really go away after you select a cell?

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit Already tried loading through the nib, but the same problem